# Karate: retry until with response expression

Tags: karate

I have an endpoint that, eventually, returns this response (before this, response is {}):

```
{ "field": { "A.B":"C" } }
```

I could not make the retry until work:

```
Given path 'endpoint'
And retry until response.field == { "A.B":"C" }
When method get
```

I couldn't figure out what I' doing wrong because this retry always fail even when the response is { "field": { "A.B":"C" } }

Thanks

Comment: because in JS the `==` sign does NOT work as you think it does. karate gives you `match` for a reason. `retry until` is designed to use JS. now please read the linked answer - and you will know what to do

Comment: Yes, I forgot it was JS. Using response.field["A.B"] == "C" worked for me because I was only interested on that key. Thanks!